# SSDT emits spurious SQL71502: Function: [dbo].[***] contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sqlclr, sql-server-data-tools

I have a number of SqlClr aggregate functions that were once in a separate project...but now with SSDT, I can have them all a single db project.  Cool.  All of them are in the global namespace.  They compile and everything works...but I still get warnings from 4 referencing T-SQL functions in the project.  The CLR function being referenced is being referenced from 7 other T-SQL functions without warnings.

I can remove the function and let the intellisense put it back in...it finds the function, too.  I reference it exactly the same way everywhere its referenced:

```
select dbo.SomeClrAggregateFunction( a.Column )
from 
  dbo.SomeTable a
  inner join
  dbo.OtherTable b
    on a.ColumnOne = b.ColumnOne
group by 
  b.SomeOtherColumn
```

Again...everything works..I can compile, deploy and test the referencing functions just fine.  I just can't get rid of the warnings.  I've got a thing about getting rid of warnings, but suppression seems unseemly.

Comment: would suppression for just that one file be considered?

Comment: Would you mind showing us the warnings?

Comment: Sorry SandRock, the warnings are gone.  It's been over a year since I visited this issue.  Rebuilt all this morning and it built clean (no suppressions, btw). I can only guess that a tool update made it go away.